# How to I install protobufs C++/Python extension?

Tags: python, c++, protocol-buffers

I'm looking to upgrade to the new protobuf version 4.21.0. I am sharing messages between python and c++, on the [release page](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/news/2022-05-06#python-updates) they mention that this capability breaks, unless I set `PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=cpp`, and ensure that the Python/C++ extension is installed.
How do I ensure that the Python/C++ extension is installed? Where do I find it? What is meant by this Python/C++ extension?
Also does the env var need to be set when generating *_pb2.py out of *.proto files or also when running python/c++ programs which are using protobuf?

Comment: Very good question. I have the same problem. I can send data from C++ to Python, but it crashes on deserialization on the way back.. I'm thinking it could be due to this extension.. but there is no link to it or other information

Comment: Nevermind, my problem was not related to the extension.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you install it [like so](https://osdevlab.blogspot.com/2016/03/how-to-install-google-protocol-buffers.html) after installing protobuf:

```
$ cd protobuf-3.21.0/
$ cd python
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../src/.libs
$ python setup.py build --cpp_implementation
$ python setup.py test --cpp_implementation
$ sudo python setup.py install --cpp_implementation
$ export PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=cpp
$ export PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION_VERSION=2
```

edit: I verified that the `--cpp_implementation` flag is still [supported](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/v21.0/python/setup.py#L226) in v21.0.